# Extract product from text

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, recurrent-neural-network

I have a task for finding product name in a large datasets of text. For example: phone Samsung S7 or Blow molding machine. I have found some resources for Named Entity Recognition and Fact extraction, but here I want to get some practical idea for implementing this task.

I have an idea to parse a lot of sites where company told about their product and then vectorize those words, using for example gensim. Then I get some vocabulary of words and their vector representation.

Then when I want train neural network I get a sentence or sliding window of 5-6 words find it in my vocabulary, get their vector representation and send to input for NN. I want to use LSTM and some settings layer. In output I set a class of entity for each word which I get in input.

But I have some question. Is this approach have normal idea? And how to pass words into input layer which is not in my vocabulary?

If you have some better idea for implementing this task please describe this.

Answer (score 1):

> But I have some question. Is this approach have normal idea?

Yes, though instead of a sliding window people tend to give the entire sentence, since recurrent neural networks can handle sentences of variable size.

> And how to pass words into input layer which is not in my vocabulary?

typically they are mappped to some UNK (unknown) token, a.k.a. OOV (out of vocabulary), the embeddings of which is one of the initialized, then jointly learnt during the  training phase.

> If you have some better idea for implementing this task please describe this.

You could add character embeddings at the bottom of your network, as well as some sequence optimization leader at the top of network. Example: https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.03475